# Edit an object in an array and display information

Tags: jquery, arrays, object, dom, dynamic

I've an array of objects (myData) which has objects with type "internal" and "external".

I'm creating divs with class="box" out of the objects in array and displaying some information of the corresponding object.

I've an edit button in the div.box, only if my object type ="external".

On clicking the edit button, I should probably be able to edit the data in a modal or popup containing input fields. These input fields will show the value of each property of that particular object from the array.
So, on click of the edit, I want to update the information(company or url) of that object in 'myData' array. Also, in the displayed div I'd then like to display the updated information.

How do I achieve this?

Here's the code :

```js
var myData = [{company: "ABC", url:"www.abc.com", type:"internal"},{company: "CDE", url:"www.cde.com", type:"internal"},{company: "DEF", url:"www.def.com", type:"external"},{company: "EFG", url:"www.efg.com", type:"internal"},{company: "FGH", url:"www.fgh.com", type:"external"}];

$('#createData').click(function(){
  createDisplay();
});

function createDisplay(){
  myData.forEach(function(obj){
    $('.container').append(
      $('<div>').addClass('box').append(
        $('<label>').text('Company Website: '),
        $('<a>').addClass('compUrl').attr('href', obj.url).text(obj.company),
        obj.type =='external'? $('<br /><button>').addClass('.edit-btn').text('Edit'): ''
      )
    )
  });
}
```

```css
.box{
  height: 100px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
   
</div>

<button id="createData">Create divs</button>
```

Comment: How are you planning to edit the data. By showing inputs instead of data ?

Comment: what should happen when you click edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To edit the data in the object and to update the display assuming you have access to the new data

```
$("body").on("click", ".edit-btn", function(){
   $anchor = $(this).siblings("a.compUrl");
   var name = $anchor.text();
   var objIndex = myData.findIndex(function(el) {
    return el.company == name
   });
   // var newCompanyName = "";
   // var newCompanyUrl =  "";
   myData[objIndex] = {
    "company": newCompanyName,
    "url": newCompanyUrl,
    "type": "external"
   };
   $anchor.attr('href', newCompanyUrl).text(newCompanyName);
});
```

**EDIT:** Updated code to include the popup for saving new data.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="updateData" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="update-data" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <!-- Modal Header -->
         <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Update Data</h4>
         </div>
         <!-- Modal Body -->
         <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
               <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="companyName">Company Name</label>
               <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="companyName" placeholder="Company Name" />
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="companyUrl">Company URL</label>
               <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="companyUrl" placeholder="Company URL" />
               </div>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" value="" id="targetRow">
         </div>
         <!-- Modal Footer -->
         <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
            Close
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="saveNewData">
            Save changes
            </button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And the JS

```
$("body").on("click", ".edit-btn", function() {
  var row = $(this).closest('.box').index();
  $("#targetRow").val(row);
  $("#updateData").modal("show");
});
$("body").on("click", "#saveNewData", function() {
  //Validate the new Data
  if (valid) {
    updateData();
    $("#companyName, #companyUrl, #targetRow").val("");
    $("#updateData").modal("hide");
  }
});

function updateData() {
  var rowIndex = $("#targetRow").val(),
    row = $(".container").find(".box").eq(rowIndex),
    newCompanyName = $("#companyName").val(),
    newCompanyUrl = $("#companyUrl").val();
  $anchor = row.find("a.compUrl");
  var name = $anchor.text();
  var objIndex = myData.findIndex(function(el) {
    return el.company == name
  });

  myData[objIndex] = {
    "company": newCompanyName,
    "url": newCompanyUrl,
    "type": "external"
  };
  $anchor.attr('href', newCompanyUrl).text(newCompanyName);
}
```

**Updated the code in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lf5xb2qw/)**

Comment: I would need to update the information using a pop up. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: @Sunny I have updated the code to include the popup for saving new data.

Comment: I'm not able to get the modal(pop-up) opened on click of the edit button. Not sure, what's the problem!

Comment: No, but somehow it doesn't work. Could you please instead put your code in a fiddle or snippet?

Comment: @Sunny Added a fiddle for the working code. In your code there was `addClass('.edit-btn')` which created the issue , the class name does not require '.' with it just the class name will do. So it should be `addClass('edit-btn')`.

Comment: @Sunny Happy to help!

Comment: I'd asked a similar question wherein I'm trying to update it a little differently, particularly when I've an object with more key-value pairs. However, in my question I've used the same data as in this one. Do you mind taking a look into that?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43627969/update-an-object-in-the-array-using-a-modal-form-and-display-updated-details

Comment: I'm sorry, but unfortunately, there's an issue with the code. If I try to update any other property which is not displayed, for example, type="internal", it doesn't get updated immediately. I'd tried something different in my another question for which I'd provided the link above..

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm just a month old in jQuery. I'd been trying pretty hard to figure out the problem to understand the problem with the code I'd written. Could you please help me?

Comment: In the other question you are calling up `submit()` which is creating up all the chaos. First update the data then POST or send it to the server. And btw the argument passed to `updateData` is the object which is being edited not the index of `.box()`. I was very specific and clear in my code. You didnt have to change it up.

Comment: Thank for the help. Your answer is valid for this question. But for my another question, I found the solution. I just need to make the variable global.

Comment: Offered you 50 bounty for all the help! :)