# Update an object in the array using a modal form and display updated details

Tags: jquery, arrays, forms, replace, modal-dialog

I'm trying to update an external object by clicking on the edit button.
It brings up a pop-up, wherein I can enter the new information and it should then update the user accordingly. 
But somehow it doesn't seem to work. It just triggers a page refresh and nothing happens at all. 
Could you please help me fix this?

```js
var myData = [{
    company: "ABC",
    url: "www.abc.com",
    type: "internal"
  }, {
    company: "CDE",
    url: "www.cde.com",
    type: "internal"
  }, {
    company: "DEF",
    url: "www.def.com",
    type: "external"
  }, {
    company: "EFG",
    url: "www.efg.com",
    type: "internal"
  }, {
    company: "FGH",
    url: "www.fgh.com",
    type: "external"
  }];

  $('#createData').click(function() {
    createDisplay();
  });
function createDisplay() {
  myData.forEach(function(obj) {
  $('.container').append(
    $('<div>').addClass('box').append(
    $('<label>').text('Company Website: '),
    $('<a>').addClass('compUrl').attr('href', obj.url).text(obj.company),
    obj.type == 'external' ? $('<br /><button>').addClass('edit-btn').text('Edit').attr({"data-toggle":"modal", "data-target":"#updateData"}) : ''
    )
  )
  });
}
$(document).on('click', '.edit-btn', function(){
 var index = getIndex(this);
  $("#updateForm").submit(function(index){
      updateData(index);
    return false;
  });
});
function getIndex(item){
  return $(item).parents('.box').index();
}

function updateData(obj) {
  companyName = $('#companyName').val();
  companyUrl = $('#companyUrl').val();

  var upObj = {
    company: companyName,
    url: companyUrl,
    type: "external"
  }
  myData.splice(index, 1, upObj);
  createDisplay();
}
```

```css
.box {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">

</div>

<button id="createData">Create divs</button>
<!-- Modal -->

<div class="modal fade" id="updateData" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="update-data" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <!-- Modal Header -->
    <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
    </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Update Data</h4>
    </div>
    <form id="updateForm">
    <!-- Modal Body -->
    <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="companyName">Company Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="companyName" placeholder="Company Name" required/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="companyUrl">Password</label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="url" class="form-control" id="companyUrl" placeholder="Company URL" required/>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal Footer -->
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
      Close
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">
      Save changes
    </button>
    </div>
  </form>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what part of your code doesn't work?

Comment: Please, before asking such a question, make sure your class references and ID references are all correct. `.edit-user`, `#newName`, `#newDob`, `#newImg` .. etc, are selectors that match nothing. It is no wonder it does not work. Also, you don't have code that fills the `#updateForm` with values. And there is a syntax error where you have not closed a parenthesis after `$(document).on('click', '.edit-user', function(){ ...`

Comment: Sincere apologies for the errors! I somehow mixed the code and that's the reason. Can I use replaceWith() here instead? Like, jQuery(obj).replaceWith(upObj)?

Comment: I had updated the code and the description and made it simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I found the problem. It was the variable index which I was using. It was being over-ridden I believe on trying submitting the form, which was causing the problem.

```js
var myData = [{
  company: "ABC",
  url: "www.abc.com",
  type: "internal"
}, {
  company: "CDE",
  url: "www.cde.com",
  type: "internal"
}, {
  company: "DEF",
  url: "www.def.com",
  type: "external"
}, {
  company: "EFG",
  url: "www.efg.com",
  type: "internal"
}, {
  company: "FGH",
  url: "www.fgh.com",
  type: "external"
}];

$('#createData').click(function() {
  createDisplay();
});
function createDisplay() {
  $('.container').empty();
  myData.forEach(function(obj) {
  $('.container').append(
    $('<div>').addClass('box').append(
    $('<label>').text('Company Website: '),
    $('<a>').addClass('compUrl').attr('href', obj.url).text(obj.company),
    obj.type == 'external' ? $('<br /><button>').addClass('edit-btn').text('Edit').attr({'data-toggle':'modal', 'data-target':'#updateData'}) : ''
    )
  )
  });
}
var currentIndex;
$(document).on('click', '.edit-btn', function(){
  currentIndex = $(this).parents('.box').index();
});
$('#updateForm').submit(function(){
  updateData(currentIndex);
  return false;
});

function updateData(index) {
  companyName = $('#companyName').val();
  companyUrl = $('#companyUrl').val();

  var upObj = {
  company: companyName,
  url: companyUrl,
  type: 'external'
  }
  myData.splice(index, 1, upObj);
  createDisplay();
}
```

```css
.box {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">

</div>

<button id="createData">Create divs</button>
<!-- Modal -->

<div class="modal fade" id="updateData" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="update-data" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <!-- Modal Header -->
    <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
    </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Update Data</h4>
    </div>
    <form id="updateForm">
    <!-- Modal Body -->
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="companyName">Company Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="companyName" placeholder="Company Name" required/>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="companyUrl">Website</label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="url" class="form-control" id="companyUrl" placeholder="Company URL" required/>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal Footer -->
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
      Close
      </button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary">
      Save changes
      </button>
    </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```